# Android Honeywell CT50: Trigger done(completed) event

Tags: android, xamarin, honeywell

I'm developing an app in xamarin forms for this device and i need to configure the "phone" to call the done event (This event is raised when the user ended input by pressing the return key on the keyboard , i have attached a print screen)after each scan and i just can't figure out how to do it . I have tried adding a carriage return as a suffix but it does not work .I can't seem to find any information about this topic online .

[Picture of what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyeel.png)

Any information and suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,

[Edit]-My app ( It's just for testing )

My xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Views.Page1"
             Title="Page1">

        <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
             <Entry Placeholder="Scan Text" Completed="Entry_OnCompleted"/>
        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Code behind :

```
 private async void Entry_OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           await DisplayAlert("Done", "Scan Completed", "Ok");
        }
```

If i press that button i get the message "Scan Completed". I want the same functionality without having to manually press that button. I want that event to be triggered after each scan (i need to know when the scanning it's done so i can do something with the scanned code). I know there is a text changed event but it's not what i need  (The scanned code does not have a standard form/length).

Comment: Please share the example code of what you have tried as of now and what is it expected to do.

Comment: I have added the code for my testing app.

Comment: Can you share how you integrated the CT50 into Xamarin.Forms

Comment: What do you mean ? It's an android device so i just installed the apk . I did not use something like a sdk for xamarin-forms for this device ( i was not able to find one) . The built in scanner work's without any special modifications . All you need to do is have your focus in a [entry](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry/) cell  before scanning. The scanner will work like a keyboard and write your scanned code in that entry .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to permanently add a scan suffix [CR] to the scanner? 
In Android 6 it is in Settings / Scanning / Internal Scanner / Default Profile / Data Processing Settings / Suffix...

Just add \r for a [CR].

Answer (score 0):

In Android 6 it is in Settings / Scanning / Internal Scanner / Default Profile / Data Processing Settings / Suffix...

Just hit return.

Done